# Google Places iOS Autocomplete results space

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

I tried to use Googles Autocomplete API and I used this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete#add_a_search_bar_to_the_top_of_a_view

My viewDidLoad method contains this:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// google autocomplete
_resultsViewController = [[GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController alloc] init];
_resultsViewController.delegate = self;
[_resultsViewController setExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars:YES];

_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]
                     initWithSearchResultsController:_resultsViewController];
_searchController.searchResultsUpdater = _resultsViewController;

[_searchController setDelegate:self];

// When UISearchController presents the results view, present it in
// this view controller, not one further up the chain.
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

// Prevent the navigation bar from being hidden when searching.
_searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
_searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeTop;
[_searchBarContainerView addSubview:_searchController.searchBar];

[_searchController setActive:YES];
```

But it's showing results like on the image. How can I remove the space from between the results and the searchbar?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve both these issues by doing the following:

**First**, set `.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false` for your `GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()` instance:

```
resultsViewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

If you run your app now, you'll see that the extra space is gone, but now the first result is underneath your search bar. To fix that, I used the `additionalSafeAreaInsets.top` property (I recommend setting it to your `searchBarContainerView`'s height, though you can use whatever value you want):

```
resultsViewController.additionalSafeAreaInsets.top = searchBarContainer.frame.height
```

**Side note:** If you support pre-iOS 11 devices, you'll have to wrap these lines in an `#available` check as `additionalSafeAreaInsets` is only available in iOS 11+. However, in my own testing I found that iOS 10 and lower didn't have this issue to begin with.